# Connect to Db2 database using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, db2, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to connect to a Db2 database from my Kotlin project,

Does Exposed support Db2?

If not what ORM can I use?

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/pull/930 and https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/1106 - doesn't seem like exposed supports DB2

Comment: DB2 - for which platform? DB2 for z/OS or DB2 LUW or DB2 for VM & VSE Server ...

Comment: Do you need an ORM or would the JDBC driver do?

Comment: Hello @Twistleton, Thank you for your reply, I need it for DB2 LUW

Comment: Hello @data_henrik , Thank you for your reply, No I need an ORM